# Salesforce unit test method to test Batch start?

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch

Is that possible to create and validate the below start method

```
public class testBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>
{   
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext batchableContextVar)
    {  
        return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Id,Name FROM User');             
    }

    ...
```

what i want is to create test class and assert the below

```
List<Sobject> sObjecList = testBatch.start(BC)//struck here to create BC
System.Assert(sObjectList.size()>0);
```

Just want to check this is possible.

Comment: Seems like when it comes to Apex batch, we are limited to integration testing as opposed to unit testing each (code path in each) method individually. I suppose that we could write additional, testable methods in the Class, and write tests against those.... if the risks justify the rewards.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you use Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() to test batchable classes, like so:

```
Test.startTest();
Database.executeBatch(new testBatch());
Test.stopTest();
```

The only drawback is that we're limited to a single batch using this method, so that's usually why you'll see either a custom query or custom limit:

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(
        [SELECT Id FROM User LIMIT :Test.isRunningTest()?1:50000000]
    );
}
```

Some people prefer to pass in a SOQL string variable, but that's just a bad idea. You should prefer inline static query statements when possible.

Comment: Agree. Bu my question is to create a test class to check the above start method ?

Comment: @bharath And the answer is, you don't, if you want to follow the testing design pattern. You should alter your start method as prescribed. If you have more than 200 users, you'll get errors otherwise.

Comment: Agree. I want to create testMethod only for start method ?

Comment: test method to ensure the query locator returns records

Comment: @bharath The goal of unit tests isn't to test a system feature. When you run a query on user records, values will be returned. That's like trying to assert that 1 + 1 = 2. If it didn't, then there'd be bigger problems to worry about. You should only worry about the logic that can actually fail, such as what the execute method does.

Comment: Agree sfdcfox. thinking on possibilities?

Comment: @bharath Test the logic you need to test. Leave system logic to the dozens of salesforce engineers that work hard to make sure your code doesn't break. There's no reason for you to go through this exercise.

Comment: Agree. But i tried the below

Comment: N.B. to @bharath note the `LIMIT :Test.isRunningTest()?1:50000000` expression is relevant when querying setup objects in `start()` - otherwise, you should be mocking objects in testmethod and batch will only find the objects you mocked. Since you are using `User` as target object without a filter, all Users in org will be fetched, including inactive ones and community users

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static testMethod void startTest()
    {
         Database.BatchableContext bc;
         Test.startTest();
         accountBatch obj=new accountBatch();
         obj.query = 'Select id from account';
         Database.QueryLocator queryLocator= obj.start(BC);
         Database.QueryLocatorIterator queryIterator =  queryLocator.iterator();
         System.assert(queryIterator.hasNext());
    }
```